# Is a flash bar needed when working with a Polaroid SX-70 Land Camera?

Tags: polaroid, instant-camera

I found some expired SX-70 film in my house, and I've been looking on ebay for a tested model of the folding Land Camera. I'm really eager to test the film out even though I know the quality probably won't be any good. Does anyone know if a flash bar is needed when operating this type of camera? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If you're shooting in daylight I don't think you'd need a flash bar assuming the film pack is still good. The developer 'pods' may be dried out by now and I would also be concerned about the embedded battery in the film pack being dead. BTW, an SX-70 film pack will only work in an SX-70 camera. The older folders used a different film format and technology.

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks for the answer. Do you know if using 600 film alongside a neutral density filter would work in old SX-70 cameras?

Comment: No idea, sorry!

Comment: Yes...you need a filter over the film pack ,or it will come out overexposed.